# How to print the contents of a popup window with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a webpage that utilises [bPopUp](http://dinbror.dk/blog/bPopup/) to pop up a modal window with jQuery.

The contents of that window are exactly what I would like to print (and nothing else on the main page).

I've tried linking a button on the popup window to run the command `window.print();` but this just prints the whole page showing the popup window obscuring the rest of the page.

Does anyone know how I can only print the contents of the pop up window and nothing else?

Thanks

Comment: `console.log($("#popup").html())`

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen apologies for my ignorance, but will this send the contents to the printer? Or just to the 'console' at the bottom of the page? Thanks

Comment: jQuery `html()`: Gets the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the HTML contents of every matched element.. See more: http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Sample HTMP**

```
<div id='DivIdToPrint'>
    <p>This is a Popup which needs to be printed.</p>
</div>

<div>
    <p>Do not print.</p>
</div>

<input type='button' id='btn' value='Print' onclick='printDiv();'>
```

**Javascript**

```
function printDiv() 
{
var divToPrint=document.getElementById('DivIdToPrint');
var newWin=window.open('','Print-Window');
newWin.document.open();
newWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">'+divToPrint.innerHTML+'</body></html>');
newWin.document.close();
setTimeout(function(){newWin.close();},10);
}
```

Give an ID to your Popup div and use above example.
You need to give inline styling to print the popup exactly.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have managed to get it working. Albeit without the formatting as you have explained. Am I right in thinking there is no way of preserving the formating? Maybe loading the relevant css file into the new window or something? Thanks again?

Comment: we might prevent the format if we can load the css file. Will have to check for it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm using Wordpress if it makes a difference? Thanks again for your help :-)

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen I've accepted this answer. It's obviously not completely what I was after as it doesn't preserve the styling but I'll try and work around that myself. Thanks to you and Sanket for all your help. :-)

Comment: @JohnT If you think you can answer a better one. you shall post your own answer and accept it. It might help future readers :) Welcome

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen please don't mis-interpret my response as being un-grateful for the help or the answer. I hope I didn't come across like that (and, if I did, I sincerely apologise). All I was meaning was that I had hoped that someone would build on the information that you and Sanket provided to allow me to preserve the styles. If I do find this though I will add it to this thread. Thanks again :-)